# Fórmula Excel com resultado incorreto

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho a seguinte fórmula:

```
=SE(1,5*Q2>F8<2*Q2;"RUIM";"BOM")
```

Em `Q2` tenho `44` e em `F8` tenho `70` e meu resultado dá `BOM`. Onde está o erro?

Comment: Não estão invertidos os valores para VERDADEIRO e FALSO?

Comment: Ismael, invertendo ai fica tudo RUIM, ou seja não está fazendo o teste lógico......

Comment: Por que fazer `1,5*Q2>F8<2*Q2`? Isso deixa muito ilegível. Colocando os valores que você definiu, fica `66 > 70 < 88`, ou seja, dá falso e por isso dá `"BOM"`.

Comment: Como você tem duas condições, pretende utilizar `E` ou `OU`? Explicando o que o Pedro disse, 66 > 70 = FALSO mas, 70 < 88 = VERDADEIRO - Consultando a tabela verdade `FALSO E VERDADEIRO = FALSO`

Comment: Pedro, o critério que preciso é: se o valor de F8 estiver entre 66 e 88 atribuo o conceito RUIM. Se estiver fora deste intervalo o conceito é BOM Qual seria então a fórmula indicada?????

Comment: Tente mudar de `1,5*Q2>F8<2*Q2` para `E(F8>=(1,5*Q2);F8<=(2*Q2))`

Answer (score 3):

Você precisará utilizar a função [`E`](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/E-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-E-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) junto a função `SE`;

`SE` o valor de F8 (70) for maior que 66 `E` menor que 88, então será "RUIM", senão, "BOM".

A fórmula será:

```
=SE(E(F8>1,5*Q2; F8<2*Q2);"RUIM";"BOM")
```

### Detalhe

Quando se trabalhar com intervalo deve se considerar se é necessário incluir os próprios valores de referência - os extremos

Veja:

```
70 > 66 = VERDADEIRO  
66 > 66 = FALSO
```

Se na sua planilha o valor de F8 for 66, então não vai entrar no conceito de "RUIM";

Fórmula para intervalo (inclusive os extremos)

```
=SE(E(F8>=1,5*Q2; F8<=2*Q2);"RUIM";"BOM")
```

**wiki**
"Em Matemática, um intervalo (real) é um conjunto que contém cada número real entre dois extremos indicados, podendo ou não conter os próprios extremos."

Comment: Pessoal deu certo com a seguinte fórmula:

Comment: =SE(E((1,5*$Q$2)<F8;(2*$Q$2)>F8);"RUIM";"B0M")

Comment: OK, agradecido a todos pela ajuda. Valeu.

Comment: @GomesAndré Ajude o site votando e/ou aceitando as respostas que te ajudaram.